# Message definition namespaces

Tags: ros, messages, namespaces, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In message definition naming is the syntax always:
package/messagedef.msg

Suppose one wants to have sets of messages for different vehicles (perhaps the hardware is sufficiently different that this makes sense). Is this possible?
package/vehicle1/messagedef.msg
package/vehicle2/messagedef.msg

Or even
package/vehicle1/status/electrical/messagedef.msg
package/vehicle2/status/electrical/messagedef.msg

Or does message naming not work in this way?

Thanks,

-Val

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238285/message-definition-namespaces/) by [vschmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25950/vschmidt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 242 on 2016-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [ROS Messages](http://wiki.ros.org/Messages) page:

> Message types use standard ROS naming
> conventions: the name of the package +
> / + name of the .msg file. For
> example, std_msgs/msg/String.msg has
> the message type std_msgs/String.

In your example, it could make sense to make a generic vehicle message say `pkgname/GenericVehicle.msg` and then create vehicle specific messages for `vehicle1` and `vehicle2`. These specific messages could then have a field entry that is the `pkgname/GenericVehicle.msg`. In this way you could compose messages that hierarchically depend on each other such that, when used in a client library, could become something like:

```
msg = pkgname.msg.Vehicle2()
msg.status.electrical.core_electrical_value = 1.0
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vschmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25950/vschmidt/) on 2016-06-29**:
Ooo. I didn't see that in the ROS Messages page. And your idea makes sense to me I think. Thanks!